# Nuget package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild fails in Dockerfile

Tags: c#, typescript, docker, asp.net-core, nuget

I have an ASP.NET Core project that includes several TypeScript files. The project has [Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild) reference to automatically compile these TS files to JavaScript files.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="3.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The setting worked until I tried to dockerize my project. When I follow [the example here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/), the error occurs:

> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/3.2.3/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(305,5):
>   error MSB6003: The specified task executable "node" could not be run.
>   No such file or directory [/app/MyProject.csproj] The
>   command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a
>   non-zero code: 1

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: For `No such file or directory [/app/MyProject.csproj]`, it seems your command running path or relative project path is wrong in the docker. Share us your docker file, project structor and where you run the command.

Answer (score 11):

On Windows, `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` includes tsc.exe. On non-Windows platforms, such as in a Docker container, `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` does not include ts.exe and instead shells out to a Node for the TypeScript compiler. The official dotnet/sdk Docker images I think included Node at one point in the past, but they no longer include Node. You will either need to make or find a Docker image with both the dotnet-sdk and Node, or configure some multi-stage build involving the official Node image.

Comment: Adding `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs` to the `Dockerfile` (based on dotnet SDK image) fixed it for me.

Comment: @Max with that I got node version 12.22 but the Microsoft.TypeScript.MsBuild includes a files using '??' which is only supported from version 14.5

Answer (score 2):

In linux containers You have to install node first. Add the following lines to your dockerfile. Add it before "RUN dotnet build"

```
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential
RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the question! Saved me from asking it myself.

For me the fix was as simple as running `sudo apt-get install nodejs` 
*(Using Ubuntu 18.04)*