# MSB6003 The specified task executable "node" could not be run

Tags: typescript

I am trying to run a .NET project on a MacBook Pro. When I do so, I get the following error:

```
  Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(320, 5): [MSB6003] The specified task executable "node" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='node', CommandLine=' /Users/me/src/my-project/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.4.6.4/tools/tsc/tsc.js @"/var/folders/2k/8jkm4std1t9fpdj72f0kt0140000gp/T/tmp0dfe86aa8cf1451394f2dbcbd5983643.rsp"', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0029f] in <5964c1f33a6b4e45985e4259425270a7>:0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in <5964c1f33a6b4e45985e4259425270a7>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool (System.String pathToTool, System.String responseFileCommands, System.String commandLineCommands) [0x000c9] in <872a4cb0cfbd47a3bbbbb3d0fe90a124>:0
  at TypeScript.Tasks.VsTsc.ExecuteTool (System.String pathToTool, System.String responseFileCommands, System.String commandLineCommands) [0x00072] in <aaeaeec0ba024e1486638c09baa65731>:0
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute () [0x00433] in <872a4cb0cfbd47a3bbbbb3d0fe90a124>:0
```

I see from [Nuget package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild fails in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007175/nuget-package-microsoft-typescript-msbuild-fails-in-dockerfile) that `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` does not include tsc.exe on Mac and is attempting to execute node. I have at least one (or more) Node version installed via NVM. How do I tell my .NET project to use that particular node?

Comment: By any chance does this help? It says older versions of MSBuild (or related launcher version) have issues launching node on other platforms, see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/4504)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your problem might be due to known issues with NVM, and the fact that NVM can sometimes fail to add Node.js to the PATH environment variable.

1. Open terminal and verify if Node is installed and PATH variable is set properly `node -v`;
2. If it doesn't work, then run `nvm use vX.X.X` so the nvm setup a node for you;
3. Restart terminal / Your IDE and try to run compilation again;

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I open a terminal and run `node --version`, I see v18.10.0 is currently active. I'm trying to run the project in JetBrains Rider, so I think it doesn't have the path to node available.

Comment: This may help configure JetBrains Rider with the correct path to Node: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Run_Debug_Configuration_Node_JS.html#s_run_config_node_configuration_tab